# Can I flag the same post twice even though my first flag was deemed invalid?

Tags: discussion, flags

I came across the post shown in the screenshot posted as a response to this question [How to eliminate 'unused output column' warnings in SSIS jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266805/how-to-eliminate-unused-output-column-warnings-in-ssis-jobs/267344#267344) The same user who gave this answer also provided another answer.

In my opinion, the following is not an answer but more like a comment. So, I flagged it and gave the following comments. `Multiple answers by OP. Merge this answer with other answer posted by OP that has 1 rep point. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266805/how-to-eliminate-unused-output-column-warnings-in-ssis-jobs/267337#267337`

I think that I erred at the part when I provided incorrect comments while flagging this post. I still feel that this post is not a real answer. Now, I think that I should have selected not an answer option while flagging this post.

1. Am I correct in my opinion that this is not a real answer?
2. Am I correct in the assumption that my comments lead the moderator to deem the flag invalid?
3. Would the answer be removed/merged if I mark it as not an answer?
4. Is it ok to flag the same post twice? Are there any etiquette that I shouldn't do that?

I understand that the moderators are very busy but it sure would be nice to see why my flag was deemed invalid so I can learn not to repeat the mistakes. The flagging summary simply shows invalid and it doesn't help me much.

I appreciate your inputs.

*Post in question:*

[image: Answer_Screenshot]

*Flagging summary shows that the flag was deemed invalid:*

[image: Flagging_Summary]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Am I correct in my opinion that this is not a real answer?

Yes, I agree that the second post by the OP was more editorial in nature, and not an answer to the question.

> Am I correct in the assumption that my comments lead the moderator to deem the flag invalid?

Probably.  "Multiple answers by OP" is a perfectly valid thing for the OP to do, so I wouldn't normally merge them.

> Would the answer be removed/merged if I mark it as not an answer?

Yes, it probably would have been.  After looking at the answer, I removed it.

> Is it ok to flag the same post twice? Are there any etiquette that I shouldn't do that?

This is an extremely rare case where I'd say it would have been okay to flag it again.  If the post changes significantly or you think your original flag was misinterpreted because you flagged it wrong, then I think it's okay to reflag a post.

Answer (score 3):

One reason some flags get marked as invalid is because they request that mods do things that the software itself isn't set up to do.

Some things I've seen requested:

- Turn comments into answers
- Accept an answer on behalf of someone else
- Remove an acceptance (by someone other than the OP)
  can't be done without deleting the answer
  usually requested because "that answer is wrong; *mine* is right!"
- Merge a duplicate question into an original such that one question gets the upvotes of both
  no one ever wants the downvotes, for some reason…
- Remove all downvotes
- Add >1 accepted answer
- Close as a duplicate of a question on another site
  that's not even mentioning the "hey mod, I know this is a dupe of *something*"
- Merge two answers

That last may be this situation; I suspect you would have had better luck with "not an answer" or "should be a comment on OPs other answer."

Answer (score 2):

We have seen earlier that flags can be marked invalid because the flag reason is not correct. Perhaps the mod believed there was no reason to merge the answers?

You don't have to flag again because by now the answer is already deleted. Perhaps by some other mod, or for another reason.